# Redirect user using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a domain which is live. In the project directory there is no index file. so when i hit the url in the browser then it show me 404 error. I wanted that when user hit the url then login.php file should be opened. Is it possible by using .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DirectoryIndex directive in .htaccess
`DirectoryIndex login.php`

Comment: Could you please provide me in a written form code
because i'm not too much familier with this 
kindly help me
I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Just create the empty .htaccess file. And paste in this code `DirectoryIndex login.php` then try.

Comment: Sir got it
Thanks for you help